# launching chrome or IE via selenium VBA

Tags: vba, google-chrome, internet-explorer, selenium

I have written a code for web data downloading using selenium VBA, it works good in Firefox, but many time Firefox is crashing. I tried to launch chrome/IE from vba but it's not properly happening. Below is my code....please help.

```
Public Sub Untitled_2()

  Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
  Dim By As New By, Assert As New Assert, Verify As New Verify, Waiter As New    Waiter

  driver.start "firefox", "https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/Account/LogOn"

  'below 2 line don't work
  driver.start "ie", "https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/Account/LogOn"
  driver.start "chrome", "https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/Account/LogOn"


  selenium.setImplicitWait 10000
  selenium.Type "css=fieldset > div.editor-field > #UserName", "xxxxxxx"
  selenium.Type "css=fieldset > div.editor-field > #Password", "xxxxxxx"
  selenium.clickAndWait "css=fieldset > p > input.button.submit"
  selenium.Click "id=menu-5"
  selenium.Click "id=menu-1"
  selenium.clickAndWait "link=U.S."
  selenium.clickAndWait "id=NDX"
  selenium.clickAndWait "link=Weighting"
  selenium.Click "id=tradeDate"
  selenium.Click "link=20"
  selenium.Select "id=timeOfDay", "label=End of Day"
  selenium.Click "id=update"
  selenium.clickAndWait "id=exportLink"

  selenium.Stop

End Sub
```

Error screenshot is as below:

[image: Error screenshot]

How to launch chrome or IE ?

My chrome driver path is 
C:\Program Files (x86)\SeleniumWrapper\chromedriver.exe"

and ie driver path is 
C:\Program Files (x86)\SeleniumWrapper\IEDriverServer.exe"

Answer (score 0):

@purnendumaity

I've been using Selenium Webdriver with VBA for a while. My feeling using it on Windows XP, 7 or 8 is, it only works well (and not very well) with Chrome. Selenium forum users have said that the most recent Firefox versions crashes with Selenium.

Well, Chrome works. Firefox crashes and IE..... (=

I've created a default macro to configure Chrome before open it. I believe that the trick is, always open a default url and then, go to your own:

```
Private Sub ConfigureChrome()
    'initiate maximazed
    selenium.addArgument "--start-maximized"
    selenium.setPreference "download.default_directory", Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ThisWorkbook.name, "")
    selenium.setPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
    selenium.setPreference "download.extensions_to_open", ""
    selenium.setPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
    selenium.setPreference "--disable-popup-blocking", ""
    selenium.setPreference "--enable-panels", ""
    selenium.Start "chrome", "http://google.com"
End Sub
```

And then:

```
Private selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

Public Sub MyCode()
    Call ConfigureChrome    
    selenium.Open URL, 30000
    'blabalbalbal
End Sub
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I know you need `selenium.Get "/"` after launching chrome, so it may be the same with IE.
You've also declared `selenium` as a web driver, but then used `driver` in your code, so maybe try the below instead:

```
Public Sub Untitled_2()

  Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
  Dim By As New By, Assert As New Assert, Verify As New Verify, Waiter As New    Waiter

  'below 2 line don't work
  selenium.Start "ie", "https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/Account/LogOn"
  selenium.Get "/"
  selenium.Start "chrome", "https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/Account/LogOn"
  selenium.Get "/"

  selenium.setImplicitWait 10000
  selenium.Type "css=fieldset > div.editor-field > #UserName", "xxxxxxx"
  selenium.Type "css=fieldset > div.editor-field > #Password", "xxxxxxx"
  selenium.clickAndWait "css=fieldset > p > input.button.submit"
  selenium.Click "id=menu-5"
  selenium.Click "id=menu-1"
  selenium.clickAndWait "link=U.S."
  selenium.clickAndWait "id=NDX"
  selenium.clickAndWait "link=Weighting"
  selenium.Click "id=tradeDate"
  selenium.Click "link=20"
  selenium.Select "id=timeOfDay", "label=End of Day"
  selenium.Click "id=update"
  selenium.clickAndWait "id=exportLink"

  selenium.Stop

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This simple trick to make open your URL in the chrome instead of data;

```
Sub test()
Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
selenium.Start "chrome", "https://www.google.co.in"
selenium.Open ("https://www.google.co.in")
End Sub
```