# Handling file download popup of chromium browsers using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, microsoft-edge, chromium

I'm using Selenium with VBA and Microsoft Edge to collect information, and download some files from a webpage. Everything works great except for the downloading part.

On this example site: https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-doc-download/, Code like

```
oWebDriver.FindElementByXPath("//a[@href=""https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_100kB.doc""]").Click
```

will result in a popup like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, it is not possible to simply change the browser's preferences in my case, because the macro will be running on a machine with limited authorization and the following setting can not be changed:

[image]

The last option can be translated to: "Ask for the storage location with every download" and it is locked.

It seems that the "Save As" popup in the first screenshot can't be accessed, neither with Selenium nor with SendKeys.

So the only option seems to be using the Windows API with VBA to somehow automate this step, however, even so, it seems to be impossible to get a handle on this pesky popup. I tried finding the window with Spy++ and it doesn't seem to show up as a separate window:
[image]

The only solution I can now think of is getting the window size of the parent Edge browser window, navigating the mouse to the approximate position of the "Save As" button, and clicking it there using VBA and the Windows API. Obviously, This is not a great solution, as it would be quite frail and can easily break with the smallest misalignment.

Is there any other way to automate this step that doesn't require moving the mouse and automating the "manual" clicking, using only VBA with Selenium?

Comment: Some ideas.. All might be bad since I dont have any experience with VBA. 1 Can you try set the oWebDriver.setPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False   like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157107/launching-chrome-or-ie-via-selenium-vba. Since edge and chome are both chromium it should be fine.

Comment: 2. If that doesn't work maybe find a portable edge browser and point the launch to that binary, again no idea how to do that in VBA it should be something similar to the java:  EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions()  options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx")) options.setBinary(new File("/path/to/edge"));

Comment: 3. Only validate that the href address is a valid one, by performing an API get call and see that it returns the file.

Comment: If I do that manually in Chrome there is no prompt. So, is this prompt specific to vba selenium where you .click ?

Comment: @art_architect thanks for the suggestions, I will try the `oWebDriver.setPreference "download.prompt_for_download"` tomorrow. I was aware of this method when writing this post and I just assumed it wouldn't work because this option is supposed to be locked (see my question). @QHarr the prompt appears in Microsoft Edge (Version 88), and unfortunately, Chrome is not available in the environment I'm working in. I apologize for the title, somehow I wrongly assumed the problem would also exist in Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

Selenium only works for browser web page automation. The pop-up is not a part of the wab page so Selenium will not be able to recognize it.

And I think any setting in Selenium including `"download.prompt_for_download"` won't have effect. The pop-up is controlled by the browser setting, and the browser setting is controlled by your group policy, you can't override it with Selenium settings.

I think the only way is to use some 3rd party UI automation library to click that option along with Selenium, just like what you said in the question.